# How do I launch a GUI application as root on user login?

Tags: gnome, startup, root, autostart

I would like to launch a Gnome application with root privileges at login.

I have tried adding a script to launch using `update-rc.d myscript.sh defaults`.

It looks like the application does launch, but it is no longer there by the time the gnome gui arrives.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Running graphical things as root is a bad idea for security but I'm going to assume you know that and that you have exhausted any other methods. You need to do two things:

1. Allow your user to run the command via `sudo` without a password  by editing `/etc/sudoers`. You can find [a brief explanation here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/118204/sudoers-simple-explanation-requested) but you're looking for something like this:

   ```
   username ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD:/path/to/command
   ```

   Obviously replace the `username` and `/path/to/command` with real values, stick that in there and then try `sudo -k /path/to/command` (the `-k` just means it'll ask for your password if it doesn't know any better - it won't ask if your sudoers edit was correct).
2. Auto-launch your application via the standard "Startup Applications", calling `sudo /path/to/command`

And that's it.

Comment: If put username ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD:/path/to/command in /etc/sudoers, sudo fails with a parse error.  ALL= NOPASSWD:/path/to/command seems to parse, but asks me for the password when I run the command.

Comment: So, it seems "username ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:/path/to/command" must be last in the sudoers file and also "username ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD:/path/to/command" does not work with Ubuntu 8.04.

Answer (score 5):

You could try to create a custom application launcher (`.desktop` file) with `gksudo <command>` as command to run, and add that laucher to the autostart settings (`System - Settings - Autostart` or `Startup`). Another way would be to put the `.desktop` file directly into `~/.config/autostart` or (for all users) `/etc/xdg/autostart`.

- [More on **autostart**ing applications in Gnome's documentation](http://developer.gnome.org/autostart-spec/);
- [HowTo add an autostart application in Gnome 3](http://linuxandfriends.com/2011/06/01/how-to-add-startup-programs-in-gnome-3/);
- [similar for Gnome 2](http://www.ghacks.net/2009/04/08/add-an-application-to-gnomes-autostart/).