# Mounting Extra Hard Disk in Ubuntu

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive, fstab, administration

I have bought a new 1TB hard disk and formatted in ext4 file system type and attached to my CPU(Already having a HD with Ubuntu installed). Following the answer given [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/333287/external-hard-disk-read-only), I tried mounting the partition inside my Home directory(/home/user) to the path /home/user/1TB, by issuing the command `sudo mount -o rw,uid=1001,gid=1001,user /dev/sdb1 1TB/`. But each time I am getting the following error.

```
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb1,
   missing codepage or helper program, or other error
   In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
   dmesg | tail  or so
```

This is `dmesg | tail` output.

```
[52645.165434] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[52647.978811] r8169 0000:02:00.0 eth0: link up
[52647.978823] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
[52653.411041] systemd-hostnamed[5821]: Warning: nss-myhostname is not installed. Changing the local hostname might make it unresolveable. Please install nss-myhostname!
[52678.211828] usb 1-1.4: USB disconnect, device number 8
[52928.283129] type=1400 audit(1418185818.128:68): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/mysqld" pid=10379 comm="apparmor_parser"
[53659.877790] EXT4-fs (sdb1): Unrecognized mount option "uid=1001" or missing value
[56166.333706] EXT4-fs (sdb1): Unrecognized mount option "uid=1001" or missing value
[56257.211210] EXT4-fs (sdb1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts:  (null)
[56439.684477] EXT4-fs (sdb1): Unrecognized mount option "uid=1001" or missing value
```

But when mounting by issuing command `sudo mount -o rw /dev/sdb1 1TB/`, it mouted succefully, but the `user` don't have the permission to create files or directories inside it.

Ultimately, what I need is, I could mount the extra HD to any folder inside my home directory and also want make it permanent. Please advice on this.

Comment: try `tail -n 3 /etc/passwd` and check the `uid` corresponds to your username.

Answer (score 0):

The `uid=` and `gid=` options do not apply to ext4 file systems.

All you need to do is mount the file system as you did (`sudo mount -o rw /dev/sdb1 1TB/`).

Then `sudo chown myusername:mygroupname 1TB`

Then you will own the file system you created and will be able to create files there as yourself.

Comment: How can i make it permanent by editing fstab ?

Comment: Add this line to /etc/fstab: `/dev/sdb1 /home/myusername/1TB ext4 rw 0 1`