# Is there any user-friendly way of using pendrives in Ubuntu?

Tags: permissions, flash, users, usb-drive

Everytime I have to put something in a pendrive from a different computer where it was formatted, I have to format it again with GParted because it is only in read-mode. I tryed even opening nautilus with privileged and it didn't work. Please, I need to find an easy way for my aunt. She doesn't want to format every time she needs to copy files from one computer to another.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Usually FAT format is very compatible with Windows, Mac and Linux. I'm using an external drive as backup and every Operating systems are accepting it without a problem.

Comment: FAT32 should be fine

Comment: Ubuntu will accept most formats, this is a permissions issue (see here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/563764/usb-devices-showing-a-read-only) What is the output of `ls /media/$USER/ -al` with the drive plugged in?

Comment: @brndn2k I think you are right, it is not a problem with the format, I curently have it in fat. This is the output: 
total 10
drwxr-x---+ 3 gal gal 4096 may 10 11:52 .
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root 4096 mar 22 11:46 ..
dr-xr-xr-x  1 gal gal 2048 feb 15 18:43 Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS amd64

Comment: I tryed the solution with most votes of user284234 in the link you provide me and it does not work :(

Comment: That looks like it's owned by root. Have you tried taking ownership? `sudo chown -R yourusername:yourusername /media/$USER/YOURDRIVE

Comment: Or you can just change the permissions `sudo chmod 777 /media/$USER -R`

Comment: @brndn2k I tryedd with the chmod option but it is not working. I can write in the pendrive from any Window-based machine, but when using Ubuntu, just from the computer I formatted it

Comment: The chown option does not work :(