# USB stick mounted as read-only CD-ROM

Tags: mount, usb-drive

I have a kingston encryptable USB stick, that when plugged into my laptop gets mounted as read-only.

I have followed the advice given [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/563764/usb-devices-showing-as-read-only), but it does not work for me.

I have tried the following:

```
df -Th
/dev/sr0                    iso9660    13M   13M     0 100% /media/user/DTVP
```

(note that the drive is actually 4GB)

```
sudo chown user /dev/sr0
sudo chgrp user /dev/sr0
```

do not yield any output, same if I apply them to `/media/user/DTVP`

```
dosfsck /dev/sr0
fsck.fat 4.1 (2017-01-24)
open: Read-only file system
```

I also tried

```
getfacl /media/user
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: media/user
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rwx
user:user:r-x
group::---
mask::r-x
other::---
```

and then try to correct in

```
sudo setfacl -m u:user:rwx /media/user
```

but still, the stick stays read-only. Curiously, on Nautilus it appears as a CD rom rather than a USB stick, and, I guess for the same reason, on GParted is not listed and cannot be reformatted.

Any pointers?

Edit: output of `journalctl -f`

```
usb 1-3: new high-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
usb 1-3: New USB device found, idVendor=0951, idProduct=160d, bcdDevice= 1.10
usb 1-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
usb 1-3: Product: DTVault Privacy
usb 1-3: Manufacturer: Kingston
usb 1-3: SerialNumber: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
usb-storage 1-3:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
scsi host1: usb-storage 1-3:1.0
mtp-probe[6223]: checking bus 1, device 5: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:04:00.3/usb1/1-3"
mtp-probe[6223]: bus: 1, device: 5 was not an MTP device
baloo_file.desktop[2203]: UdevQt: unhandled device action "bind"
mtp-probe[6239]: checking bus 1, device 5: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:04:00.3/usb1/1-3"
mtp-probe[6239]: bus: 1, device: 5 was not an MTP device
kernel: scsi 1:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Kingston DTVault Privacy  PMAP PQ: 0 ANSI: 0 CCS
kernel: scsi 1:0:0:1: CD-ROM            Kingston DTVault Privacy  PMAP PQ: 0 ANSI: 0 CCS
kernel: sd 1:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
kernel: sr 1:0:0:1: [sr0] scsi3-mmc drive: 0x/0x writer tray
kernel: sr 1:0:0:1: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr0
kernel: sr 1:0:0:1: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 5
kernel: sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI removable disk
kernel: ISO 9660 Extensions: Microsoft Joliet Level 3
kernel: ISO 9660 Extensions: RRIP_1991A
systemd[1]: Started Clean the /media/user/DTVP mount point.
udisksd[1336]: Mounted /dev/sr0 at /media/user/DTVP on behalf of uid 1000
```

Comment: Smells like a Kingston support question. ALL storage devices are encryptable - these on-stick-encrypted devices are not really ordinary USB sticks at all - they are computing devices that *present* as a USB stick (like phones do), and do their own on-board processing.

Comment: I should probably mention that I am not able to launch the linux applications on the USB stick either...

Comment: Does is have a Windows-corrupted NTFS filesystem on it? What does `journalctl -f` show when you insert the USB stick?

Comment: @waltinator, I have added that into my question above. I should specify that I can copy the file kingston's files _out_ of the USB stick