# After running clonezilla my external HDD is mounted read only

Tags: mount, permissions, clonezilla

I've run clonezilla (didn't finish and just exit in the middle) and set my dest drive as my /dev/sdd1 2TB I've unmounted using `sudo umount /home/partimag/` and now when I mount my external HDD it's marked as read only.

I can execute this command:

```
sudo mount -o remount,uid=1000,gid=1000,rw /dev/sdd1
```

as pointed in this question [external hard disk READ ONLY](https://askubuntu.com/questions/333287/external-hard-disk-read-only) but after unmouning and mouning again it's mounted as read only with root as owner.

How can I make it again writable with my user as owner without the need to execute that command each time? Do I need to reboot? I don't want to.