# External drive is considered read-only on shell and in Nautilus

Tags: mount, nautilus, files, directory, drive

I am connecting an external drive from Intenso to my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.
Both in Nautilus and on the command line I am not allowed to write/delete/change files and folders.
For instance, mkdir says:
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘test’: Read-only file system

I tried the accepted answer from this question:
[external hard disk READ ONLY](https://askubuntu.com/questions/333287/external-hard-disk-read-only)
However, then I can e.g. create files for a few minutes. Afterwards the drive appears read-only again.

Any idea how to overcome this?

Comment: More info is needed: File system? If NTFS you may have to use the Windows native error correction tools.

Comment: Ubuntu says the file system is "msdos". I suppose it is NTFS.