# Cannot write to hard drive

Tags: hard-drive

I have this problem when I try to copy a folder from my desktop to hard drive in my computer - when I drag the folder to the DATA disk window, nothing happens. When I try to copy the folder in terminal:

```
cp -r folder/ //dev/sda2/
```

I get : cp: failed to access '//dev/sda2/': Not a directory
I also tried to change permissions as:

```
sudo chmod u=rwx /dev/sda2
```

But it didn't help. Please help, I am new to Ubuntu (I have 18.04)

As an output of `mount` i get (my '/dev/sda2' is on the bottom of the list):

```
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,relatime,size=4008528k,nr_inodes=1002132,mode=755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,size=806244k,mode=755)
/dev/sdb2 on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro)
securityfs on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
tmpfs on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k)
tmpfs on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=755)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/unified type cgroup2 (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,nsdelegate)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,xattr,name=systemd)
pstore on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
efivarfs on /sys/firmware/efi/efivars type efivarfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/pids type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,pids)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/rdma type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,rdma)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpu,cpuacct)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/memory type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,memory)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,freezer)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/hugetlb type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,hugetlb)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/devices type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,devices)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,blkio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,perf_event)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls,net_prio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,net_cls,net_prio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuset)
systemd-1 on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=35,pgrp=1,timeout=0,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct,pipe_ino=18864)
mqueue on /dev/mqueue type mqueue (rw,relatime)
debugfs on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw,relatime)
hugetlbfs on /dev/hugepages type hugetlbfs (rw,relatime,pagesize=2M)
fusectl on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw,relatime)
configfs on /sys/kernel/config type configfs (rw,relatime)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/gnome-calculator_260.snap on /snap/gnome-calculator/260 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/dev/sdb1 on /boot/efi type vfat (rw,relatime,fmask=0077,dmask=0077,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/gnome-logs_45.snap on /snap/gnome-logs/45 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/gnome-3-26-1604_74.snap on /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/74 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/gtk-common-themes_818.snap on /snap/gtk-common-themes/818 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/mailspring_346.snap on /snap/mailspring/346 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/gnome-system-monitor_57.snap on /snap/gnome-system-monitor/57 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/spotify_35.snap on /snap/spotify/35 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/core_6350.snap on /snap/core/6350 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/gnome-characters_139.snap on /snap/gnome-characters/139 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
tmpfs on /run/user/121 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=806240k,mode=700,uid=121,gid=125)
tmpfs on /run/user/1000 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=806240k,mode=700,uid=1000,gid=1000)
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/1000/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=1000)
/dev/sda2 on /media/monika/DATA type fuseblk (ro,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096,uhelper=udisks2)
```

I can't even create a new folder in the DATA disk window, if it helps.

Comment: how is /dev/sda2 mounted? Can you post the output out `$ mount` ?

Comment: Your command looks like you're trying to copy to a device (sda2) and not the mounted file-system that you should have mounted first. ie. you `mount` /dev/sda2 to a directory, and then use it via that directory.

Answer (score 2):

You can't directly write files to /dev/sda2, it's not really a directory in the same sense as you'd think of a directory in Windows, it's more like a "special file." 
You need to first mount it, and then use it as a directory.
You'll need to create a mount point, say

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/sda2
```

and then mount the partition,

```
sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt/sda2
```

All of this will is assuming the case that sda2 partition exists on your drive.

Comment: I tried 'sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt/sda2' and got 'Mount is denied because the NTFS volume is already exclusively opened.
The volume may be already mounted, or another software may use it which
could be identified for example by the help of the 'fuser' command.'

Comment: Update the question with output of    `mount`

Comment: @Monika what error does it show when u try to create a folder in  /media/monika/DATA ?

Answer (score 2):

[This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/333287/how-to-fix-external-hard-disk-read-only) solved my problem, it was only a matter of permissions

```
sudo mount -o remount,uid=1000,gid=1000,rw /dev/sda2
```