# Permission Denied when I try to copy files to another partition

Tags: permissions, copy

When I try to copy downloaded files to other partition, I get an error like in this picture:
[image: the permission denied]

The partition is `dev/sda6` which is empty and I want to use as and partition that just for saving files. Can someone help me?

Comment: Do you understand how file and directory permissions work in Linux? Or are you asking for training resources?

Comment: i just buy a new fresh harddisk, i just installed linux on this laptop. i understand a bit of linux it look like i just realize i need to learn more about linux tho.

Comment: Ask Ubuntu is not a forum, please don't add "Solved" to the title. The correct way to indicate you have found a working solution here is by accepting the most helpful answer (which you already did).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /media/agung/27820dc5-7261*
```

This will enable read, write and execute capability on the partition. Which means you can store files on it.

Comment: Thank you. it look like i need to read more about linux. thanks by the way.

Comment: This particular set of permissions (777) means that *everybody in the universe* can read and write to your hard drive. Dream access for malware or exploit. While a useful, quick hack, don't make this sort of access a habit. Disabling filesystem protections is the equivalent of throwing your headlights away because you think you will never need to drive at night. Someday you might just want that safety device after all.

Answer (score -1):

If you see 'Permission denied' or 'permission does not allow pasting files in this folder', this means you can only access the file as the root. If you want to do this via a file manager like nautilus, simply type this via your terminal:

```
sudo -H nautilus
```

Now you can read, write, and execute files. You can also set your file permission to 003 in fstab (computer > etc/fstab) this will give you (owner) and groups the read/write/execute access but any other person, just the read access. I think this is safer than 777 as suggested in the previous comment. The default in Ubuntu is 002. More information is given in [How to fix external hard disk READ ONLY?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/333287/how-to-fix-external-hard-disk-read-only)