# Ubuntu 20.04 Touro External HDD 1TB HFS+ always Read Only

Tags: 20.04, external-hdd, read-only, hfs+

I have External HDD 1TB ex. used with MAC OS mojave.
Now I use Ubuntu 20.04 as my primary OS. **When I plug it HDD to ubuntu it's always read only**.

I was try [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/333287/how-to-fix-external-hard-disk-read-only) post still no lucky.

this is information about environment:

`fdisk -l /dev/sdb`

```
Disk model: Mobile          
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 2C77B322-8C16-401C-9466-C93C50A3AF0A

Device          Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sdb1          40     409639     409600   200M EFI System
/dev/sdb2      409640 1953195991 1952786352 931,2G Apple HFS/HFS+
/dev/sdb3  1953196032 1953456127     260096   127M Microsoft basic data
```

Comment: Will you continue to use this external hard drive with MacOS? Or will it always be used with Ubuntu?

Comment: It's prepared for both ubuntu and macOs.
But I found no solution for it. So I decide to format it with NTFS.
copied it's data first of course.