# Dolphin Mounts Partition As Read-Only

Tags: partitioning, permissions, mount, fstab, ntfs

I'm running Kubuntu 21.10 on my computer and I have two partitions I use a lot, my root partition (with all of the OS stuff) and my other NTFS data partition, with games and large files. As always, my root folder is in the fstab, but my other partitions isn't (and I don't really need or want it to be.) Usually I mount the other partition and everything is going normal, but today I noticed it somehow got mounted as read-only, even though I haven't change any settings that would affect it (that I know of). Usually I mount it using the Dolphin File Manager, but of course that results in it being set as read-only. [This post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/333287/how-to-fix-external-hard-disk-read-only) explains how you can remount it with the correct settings, but this is only a temporary solution, and their "permanent fix" doesn't fix the core problem. How can I make sure Dolphin mounts the partition as writable?

Edit: This seems to affect all mounted partitions, why?

Edit 2: Even after running the non-permanent command, I still can't modify anything on the partition despite Dolphin telling me I can.

Comment: Do you dual boot with Windows?

Comment: @Nmath yes i do dualboot

Comment: Did you turn off the hybrid suspend in Windows? (Fast Startup) This must be disabled.

Comment: You probably had a Windows update which may turn fast start up back on. With hibernation flag set, Linux NTFS driver will not mount read/write to prevent any damage or loss of data in a hibernated partition.

Comment: @oldfred So I should restart my computer into Windows and disable hibernation and then come back to Linux?

Comment: Exactly, disable Fast Startup and then shutdown Windows.

Answer (score 5):

You must disable "Fast Startup" in Windows.

Fast Startup is actually a hybrid suspend. When the system is suspended this way, any shared volumes can only be mounted as "read-only" in Ubuntu.

This option is incompatible with sharing volumes with Windows in a dual-boot configuration.