# 13.10, mount works only in read-only mode

Tags: 13.10, mount, read-only

No success mounting a device in read-write mode. After plugging it in, it is mounted.

```
$ sudo lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,LABEL
NAME   FSTYPE    SIZE MOUNTPOINT         LABEL
sda            238,5G                    
├─sda1 ext4    230,6G /                  
├─sda2             1K                    
└─sda5 swap      7,9G [SWAP]             
sdb            931,5G                    
├─sdb1 vfat      200M                    EFI
└─sdb2 hfsplus 931,2G /media/cr/FinnHard FinnHard
sr0             1024M 


$ sudo mount -o remount,rw  '/media/cr/FinnHard'
mount: /media/cr/FinnHard not mounted or bad option


$ sudo umount /media/cr/FinnHard 
$ sudo mount -t hfsplus -o rw  /dev/sdb2 '/media/FinnHard'
mount: warning: /media/FinnHard seems to be mounted read-only.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're running into the problem [described here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/332315/how-to-read-and-write-hfs-journaled-external-hdd-in-ubuntu-without-access-to-os).  You should be able to mount that volume read/write by running:

```
sudo apt-get install hfsprogs
sudo mount -t hfsplus -o remount,force,rw /media/cr/FinnHard
```

You'll be able to mount it again later on using:

```
sudo mount -t hfsplus -o force,rw /dev/sdb2 /media/cr/FinnHard
```