# How to change read-only permission under 501 user?

Tags: permissions, chown

I have a hard disk that install on it mac osx 10.4.11, so I plugged that to my Ubuntu system and now I can see all of the files, but it's just read only under the 501 user permission

I'm root in Ubuntu and I tried to copy files on it via chown, but I can't, this hdd has 3 partitions and all of them are read-only under 501 permission. 
I wrote this under root in shell

```
chown -R foldername
chown -R filename
```

thank you

Comment: OSX uses HFS, a proprietary Apple file system, and it's mounted as read only by default. Here is how to mount it read/write: http://superuser.com/questions/84446/how-to-mount-a-hfs-partition-in-ubuntu-as-read-write. duplicate -> http://askubuntu.com/questions/332315/how-to-read-and-write-hfs-journaled-external-hdd-in-ubuntu-without-access-to-os