# External hard drive Dead ??

Tags: hard-drive

Hi guy's my seagate 3TB external hard drive isnt showing up on any of my PC's or Laptops. Running windows 8.1-win 10 OS and Linux Ubuntu and kali linux and 
Mint and exen parten magic shows no external mounted . the external runs and theres no ticking or odd sound the blue light comes on ... can any one help . a friend said a person who used my external borrowed it and possibly formated on his imac (Dick head) . it has all my childs photos on it n no back up appart from the Ex ...... n she not really the help me type haha

Comment: If it's not showing on any as said `try it on a mac` to see if it be seen then `transfer your photos to an external` that will seen by your other OSes or devices

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read and write HFS+ journaled external HDD in Ubuntu without access to OS X?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/332315/how-to-read-and-write-hfs-journaled-external-hdd-in-ubuntu-without-access-to-os)

Comment: It's really possible to be formatted by iMac. I've never touched but I've heard some things. So if this is the real situation don't hurry to do anything. The information still there! (3T can't be SSD) Find some tool who can recover formatted HDD. About 10 years ago, I was in the same trouble. About 99% of my data were recovered. Sorry, but it was so long ago that I don't remember anything concrete.

Comment: What's the output of `lsusb` and `sudo lsblk -f` (with the drive plugged in via USB)?

Answer (score 2):

Use 'udevadm monitor' and then plug your hard drive in. If you get output telling you where your hard drive gets mounted, then it is being recognized and mounted.

After that, you can use tools such as photorec to scan your entire hard drive and recover the photos regardless of the filesystem and mounting it. It scans for photo file signatures and recovers them.

If it is recognized and you have a device node placed in the /dev directory, you can use 'dd if= of=' to make a backup of the hard drive.

You can use 'blkid ' to show you the block id of the device, basic information such as filesystem type and label.

If the hard drive is not detected and no node is added to the /dev directory, you can try placing it in a freezer for awhile and then plugging it in. Sometimes this can give a hard drive a last breath of life to recover data.

Hope this helps! Kyle