# Cannot mount +hfs wrong fs type | bad superblock

Tags: mount

I am pretty new on Ubuntu.
I was trying to mount my +hfs formated external hard drive and all of the sudden it didn't work anymore.
I get the following error:

```
Error mounting /dev/sdc1 at /media/****/LaCie: Command-line `mount -t
"hfsplus" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid" "/dev/sdc1" 
"/media/****/LaCie"' exited with non-zero exit status 32: mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdc1, missing codepage or helper program, or other error

In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try dmesg | tail or so.  (udisks-error-quark, 0)
```

`dmesg` gives me this:

```
blk_update_request: critical medium error, dev sdc, sector 387418

Buffer I/O error on dev sdc1, logical block 48427, async page read

hfsplus: failed to load attributes file
```

already created an image with ddrescue on a different external HD, but cannot mount it due to the same error.

**How can I successfully mount such drive?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read and write HFS+ journaled external HDD in Ubuntu without access to OS X?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/332315/how-to-read-and-write-hfs-journaled-external-hdd-in-ubuntu-without-access-to-os)

Comment: please review this link http://askubuntu.com/questions/332315/how-to-read-and-write-hfs-journaled-external-hdd-in-ubuntu-without-access-to-os note that `quote` aren't needed, more info about the syntax and an example can be found there