# Unable to access files on Mac HDD from Ubuntu partition

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, permissions

I have installed 16.04 on my macbook recently for use with work etc, and have not really had any issues up to this point, but I would simply like to access the files on my Mac partition, namely music files from Ubuntu.

I am able to mount the drive fine, see quite a few folders, but as soon as I try and access the downloads/music folder, I am unable to access anything due to permissions.

If I use the `gksudo nautilus`command, I am able to access everything fine, but it doesnt really make things easier as I ideally just like to be able to access as a normal user.

Information I've found so far seems outdated.

Comment: How do you mount that disk?  Show us the command or the /etc/fstab if you use that.

Comment: I don't use a command to access it. It appears in the files GUI and lets me access it through that.

I did install hfsprogs which may be the reason for that however.

Comment: As I don't know anything about a Mac,  I can merely assume that you only have view rights if you do not actually mount it.  Please look at `https://askubuntu.com/questions/332315/how-to-read-and-write-hfs-journaled-external-hdd-in-ubuntu-without-access-to-os`. Hopefully that will help you further.