# External hardrive is read only: how to add write permissions

Tags: mount, hard-drive, read-only

I am having difficulty writing to an external HD. When I plug it in, it mounts but only as read-only.

I have installed

```
  sudo apt-get install hfsprogs
```

I have tried the following, from

[How to read and write HFS+ journaled external HDD in Ubuntu without access to OS X?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/332315/how-to-read-and-write-hfs-journaled-external-hdd-in-ubuntu-without-access-to-os)

This involved unmounting the drive

```
  sudo umount /dev/sdf1
```

Creating a new mount point

```
  sudo mkdir /media/ext2
```

and then

```
  sudo mount -t hfsplus -o force,rw /dev/sdf1 /media/ext2
```

This did not work. I have also tried deleting this mount point

```
  sudo rmdir /media/ext2
```

Recreating it and trying again but no luck.

Any further suggestions - I know this has been asked ad nauseum but none of the available solutions have worked for me.

Many thanks

EDIT: The HD was originally used on a Mac and was journaled. I disabled this and remounted in my Ubuntu system. Still  impossible to write to it. 
Ubuntu is truly rubbish - you spend all day trying to figure out how to do the simplest things.