# Ubuntu reports incorrect available space on HFS external RAID

Tags: mount, disk, disk-usage, hfs+, raid5

I have a Stardom 24TB external RAID formatted as HFS+. It shows up as a 24TB disk, but available space is only 66GB when only 6.4TB is used. When mounted in MacOS I get the correct amount of available space.

I mounted the disk with `sudo mount -t hfsplus -o force,rw /dev/sdXX /mnt/XX`, reading and writing to the disk is working fine.

Tried it with both Ubuntu 18.04 and Linux Mint 19, same result.

What am I doing wrong?

[Here's a screenshot from disk manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F4T9g.png)

Comment: Why are you mounting with `force`? Also output of `df -h`, I have had a lot of issues with disk manager reporting weird things

Comment: Hm, I followed a tutorial (https://askubuntu.com/questions/332315/how-to-read-and-write-hfs-journaled-external-hdd-in-ubuntu-without-access-to-os) about how to mount HFS drives, not sure why the force option is in there to be honest, I'm no expert at this. At the beginning it was read-only, so I did a chown command to get write access, don't know if that has anything to do with it. `df -h` shows only 5,9T available space in total.