# how to reformat USB drive on lubuntu 18.10 for macOSX compatibility?

Tags: lubuntu, live-usb, usb-drive, format, macosx

I have a 16 GB SanDisk USB stick formatted as a Lubuntu 16.04 LTS i386 startup USB drive. How do I reformat it in Lubuntu 18.10 to be a "regular" USB drive to move files between macOS and Lubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest re-formatting your [usb-thumb] device using `KDE partition Manager`

If you select your device, and click "New" you will see a window like
[image]

To have the drive recognized and usable in both OSes you need to use a format both can use. The most likely chosen is probably 'fat32'  (not 'ext4' which my box and screengrab shows; fat32 can be used by windows computers as well, but note it has a maximum filesize that can be reached for very long HD.videos).

Mac only formats can likely also be selected, as I don't use a mac - I'll point you to [How to read and write HFS+ journaled external HDD in Ubuntu without access to OS X?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/332315/how-to-read-and-write-hfs-journaled-external-hdd-in-ubuntu-without-access-to-os) which provides information about what packages must be added to add HFS support to your box).

note: my image was taken from 19.04; but I'd expect it to look pretty much the same as 18.10