# Change the mounting point for a HFS+ formated drive

Tags: mount, hard-drive, fstab, hfs+

I followed the instructions in [How to read and write HFS+ journaled external HDD in Ubuntu without access to OS X?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/332315/how-to-read-and-write-hfs-journaled-external-hdd-in-ubuntu-without-access-to-os)

I used the command:

```bash
sudo mount -t hfsplus -o force,rw /dev/sdXY /media/mntpoint
```

The drive mounts in the directory I pointed it to. It works perfectly, but I would like to change the name of the directory. I failed in all conventional ways. I thought the path was stored in the `fstab` file but there I only have my NAS device. 
I am a Linux newbie. Hopefully, someone has a solution.

Answer (score 0):

First, create a folder in any path you would like to:

```
$ sudo mkdir /home/mountpoint
```

Then just mount in this folder:

```
$ sudo mount -t hfsplus -o force,rw /dev/sdXY /home/mountpoint
```

And about the `/etc/fstab` file: it mounts devices automatically, but just if the deivce is connected to your computer in boot time!

<sub>Note: mount command ususaly identify the format, so you don't need to specify `-t hfsplus`, and for `-o` (options), it mounts `rw`, so all you need to do is:</sub>

```
$ sudo mount /dev/sdXY /home/mountpoint
```