# Why won't mounting a USB with -o rw give it read/write permissions?

Tags: usb, permissions, mount, hard-drive, read-only

I have an external hard drive. I need to put an mp4 file from `~/Documents` onto the hard drive (so onto `/media/naomi/SeagateByMe`, since I named the external hard drive SeagateByMe). However, when I run `mv safetyInAngerFirstChunk.mp4 /media/naomi/SeagateByMe` I then get `mv: inter-device move failed: 'safetyInAngerFirstChunk.mp4' to '/media/naomi/SeagateByMe/safetyInAngerFirstChunk.mp4'; unable to remove target: Read-only file system`

So I tried a bunch of stuff based on other people's posts (mostly "mount" command with a bunch of different options, and also the "killall Thunar" thing), none of which worked. One concrete thing I don't understand, which is what I'd like an answer to on here, is why this happens:

Command: `sudo umount /media/naomi/SeagateByMe`

Command: `sudo umount /dev/sda2`

------> Output: `umount: /dev/sda2: not mounted.`

Command: `sudo mount -o rw /dev/sda2 /media/naomi/SeagateByMe`

Command: `mount | grep "Seagate"`

------> Output: `/dev/sda2 on /media/naomi/SeagateByMe type hfsplus (ro,relatime,umask=22,uid=0,gid=0,nls=utf8)`

Specifically what I don't understand is why it still says "ro" in that last output line, even though I just did "-o rw" without any errors popping up. **Am I misunderstanding something, and those two things aren't related? Also, is the "ro" in that mount output line talking about the same "Read-only file system" error from the beginning, or are those two separate issues?**

The reason that this happened in the first place (I'm pretty sure) is that I opened kdenlive as root so that I could render a video straight to the external hard drive (which seemed to require root permissions) and then messed up some double versus single quotes in the file path that I told it to render to (yes, I know, "don't use random software as root, that's dumb, things will get messed up, blah blah blah" I just have incompetent moments sometimes!). Because I used the "mv" command with the exact same format as above (just with a different USB device and a different video file) *before* the kdenlive thing happened and it worked fine.

edit: I tried plugging in some other hard drives/USBs and it looks like the hsfplus ones are read-only whereas vfat ones are read-write?? Why is that?

Comment: **Try according to [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/332315/how-to-read-and-write-hfs-journaled-external-hdd-in-ubuntu-without-access-to-os).**  -- If still problems, it is possible that the file system is dirty (was shut down without flushing the buffers) or damaged. In such cases Linux will often default to mounting read-only. You can try to repair the file system, and Apple file systems should be repaired using a Apple operating system.