# Recover data from hfs hdd

Tags: external-hdd, hfs+

I have a problem with an hdd (FileSystem: hfs). When I plugged it on my pc I can't open it and from Disk this is what I see:[disk info][1].
When I try to  mount it manually I get this error: `

> mount: /mnt/myhdd: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdd, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.`

I can see the hdd with lsblk but not with fdisk...

Can someone help me to recover the data?

Edit: I'm trying to open it from ubuntu
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EtM7w.png

Comment: What is the OS of the computer you are trying to access from? You have given no info here.

Comment: Hierarchical File System (HFS) is a proprietary file system developed by Apple Inc. for use in computer systems running Mac OS. This should have been in your question.

Comment: Can you add your mount command to your question. There seems to be an answer to this here https://askubuntu.com/questions/332315/how-to-read-and-write-hfs-journaled-external-hdd-in-ubuntu-without-access-to-os

Comment: [This link](https://superuser.com/questions/392702/which-file-system-to-use-in-between-osx-and-linux) may be helpful.

Comment: Is there any reason to suspect, that the drive or the file system is damaged? Are you sure that it is HFS (or could it be some other file system, that Ubuntu *thinks* is HFS)? Would you be able to access the HFS file system from a native operating system (MacOS), and write the data to an intermediate file system, that works with both MasOS and Ubuntu (for example exFAT)?

Comment: Show us the output of `blkid`, and of `sudo parted /dev/sda print` (replace "/dev/sda" with your actual disk device as shown by `blkid`). And maybe also `lsblk -o NAME,TYPE,SIZE,FSTYPE,LABEL,TRAN,PARTLABEL`