# Trying to mount my old MACBook HDD HFS+ onto ubuntu 20.04.05

Tags: mount, macbook-pro, hfs+

The power button on my MacBook Pro stopped working. While I source a new one I'm trying to access and copy some files I need off the HDD which I have slaved through a USB connection.

When I connect the 2.5" HDD Ubuntu sees it but won't mount it. See screenshot
[Unable to mount MacBook HDD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BRL5e.png)

Here is a screen shot of what the USB HDD looks like in disks. See screenshot
[500GB HDD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xkany.png)

I've tried these commands and got the below results.
sudo mount /dev/sdb
mount: /dev/sdb: can't find in /etc/fstab.
sudo mount /dev/sdb2
mount: /dev/sdb2: can't find in /etc/fstab.
sudo mount -t hfsplus -o force,rw /dev/sdb /media/mntpoint
mount: /media/mntpoint: mount point does not exist.

It also seems the thing to do on these kind of issues is to run lsusb so the results are below
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0a5c:216c Broadcom Corp. BCM43142A0 Bluetooth Device
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 05c8:036e Cheng Uei Precision Industry Co., Ltd (Foxlink) Webcam
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp.
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 152d:0578 JMicron Technology Corp. / JMicron USA Technology Corp. JMS567 SATA 6Gb/s bridge
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

I'm a total newbie and have no idea where to go from here, can anyone help?

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/332315/how-to-read-and-write-hfs-journaled-external-hdd-in-ubuntu-without-access-to-os

Comment: Indeed ^^^ old but mostly valid.

Comment: Perfect, file system checked, sorted and now the HDD is mounted as required. :)