# Replacing gksudo with pkexec: editor doesn't start in current folder

Tags: gksudo, pkexec

I'm trying to be a good boy and stop using `gksudo`, especially since it just got orphaned in the 18.04 daily builds (note, this question is *not* specific to 18.04).

In the bad old days of using `gksudo`, I'd typically navigate to a folder containing the file I wish to edit (I use pcmanfm) then select **Tools/Open Current Folder In Terminal** from the menu.  Then I'd type `gksudo leafpad [file-I-wish-to-edit]` in the newly opened terminal.

Using information in the very useful answer [How to configure pkexec?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/287845/how-to-configure-pkexec) I set my .bash_aliases and I am able to now type `pkexec leafpad [file-I-wish-to-edit]` in the newly opened terminal and I don't get any errors.  Sadly, though I get a blank file instead of what I wanted. I have determined that this is because leafpad is looking in `/root` instead of the folder I wished to be in.

How can I maintain my halo, continue to use `pkexec` instead of `gksudo`, yet retain the functionality I'm used to?

Comment: It was orphaned in 16.04. Use `sudo apt install gksu`.

Comment: I have the packages but I'd like to do things the proper way if it's not too much trouble.  Surely this basic functionality is still available.

Comment: Yes I too fell into the "proper way rabbit hole" when **16.04** was released. So I wrote the `gsu` script which I posted in the answer below. It's nicer because it doesn't dim all attached screens like  `gksu` does. I guess it's nice because it "follows the rules" but I honestly have had no problems with `gksu`. The exception being using `gksu gedit` in Windows 10 (within WSL framework) where Windows 10 Ubuntu 16.04 messes up permissions within NTFS in the first place anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, `gksu` was "orphaned" in **16.04** but you can still install it with:

```
sudo apt install gksu
```

That said I made a wrapper script for `pkexec` a long time ago that might be of some interest:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Usage: gsu gedit file1
#  -OR-  gsu natuilus /dirname

COMMAND="$1" # extract gedit or nautilus
ABSOLUTE_NAME=$(realpath "$2")

pkexec "$COMMAND" "$ABSOLUTE_NAME"

#log-file "$ABSOLUTE_NAME" ~/bin/log-gsu-"$COMMAND"
```

I named the wrapper `gsu` as a short form of `gksu`. The `log-file` script is a separate project which I commented out in the script for this answer.

You need to setup `gedit` and `nautilus` policy kits before you can use this script as the comments reference. In your case you would need to setup a policy kit for `leafpad`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: @OrganicMarble Actually it's my pleasure to finally share it with someone who might care a couple of years after writing it :)

Comment: Thanks, this definitely helped me solve my problem. I wrote a wrapper script much like yours just for leafpad which incorporated pkexec just as you did.  With this I can execute my use case that is spelled out in the question.  I have to get used to typing gleafpad but I was going to have to get used to typing pkexec leafpad anyway. Many thanks.

Comment: Another option is to call your script `/home/your_user_name/bin/leafpad` and it will be higher on the hierarchy list and call the regular `leafpad` in `/bin` or wherever it resides.

Comment: It appears that for 18.04 they've taken gksu out of the repos, you can't even install it without manually downloading the packages.

Comment: So no longer **orphaned** like 16.04 but **kidnapped!**

Answer (score 1):

I use this alternative in desktop launchers or bash scripts to keep the gksu feel:

```
bash -c 'sudo -i nautilus;'
```

... though no pkexec here - pls don't tell my admin.

Comment: You are recommending to use sudo with graphical applications, which, even which the -i option, allegedly is not appropriate. If it were so easy, we probably would not be concerned with pkexec or admin:// after lacking the old gksu.

Comment: `sudo -H nautilus` is safer

Answer (score 0):

Use something like `pkexec thunar %f` (thunar is the xfce file manager and `%f` is for current path - works with Bionic XFCE just like gksu).