# How to install an application that requires gksu package on ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: software-installation, 18.04, gksu

I downloaded the Upwork desktop App on ubuntu 18.04. When I open it with Gdebi package installer I saw this error:

[image]

I tried to install `gksu` manually via `sudo apt install gksu` but I got this error

```
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package gksu is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'gksu' has no installation candidate
```

How can I install this software on ubuntu 18.04 (I download it yesturday so it is the most recent version on upwork website) ?

Comment: You find some alternatives in the following link, [Why don't gksu/gksudo or launching a graphical application with sudo work with Wayland?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/961967/why-dont-gksu-gksudo-or-launching-a-graphical-application-with-sudo-work-with-w/961978#961978). A simple alternative is `sudo -H GUI-application-program`, but there are alternatives with higher security, for example `pkexec`. When you get used to *text mode command lines* (in terminal windows), you are no longer affected by this problem.

Comment: pkexec with higher security accompanied by a higher probability of causing error messages, so test the app for error messages when using pkexec.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fake a package version installed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18192/how-to-fake-a-package-version-installed)

Comment: Highly related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1026800/replacing-gksudo-with-pkexec-editor-doesnt-start-in-current-folder

Comment: Extremely related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1008266/dependency-is-not-satisfiable-libatk-bridge2-0

Comment: **Close Voters:** Initially I voted along with @muru duplicate candidate but retracted after reading Nobert's answer below which will server the OP much better because there will actually be a `gksu` app for the parent to call. Plus OP is satisfied and accepted answer.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

## Introduction

As  Jeremy Bicha [wrote](https://jeremy.bicha.net/2018/04/18/gksu-removed-from-ubuntu/):

> Posted on April 18, 2018 by Jeremy Bicha — 8 Comments
>
> Today, gksu was [removed from Ubuntu 18.04](https://launchpad.net/bugs/1740618), four weeks after it was [removed from Debian](https://jeremy.bicha.net/2018/03/21/gksu-is-dead/).

So theoretically speaking there are no packages on Bionic Beaver 18.04 LTS, depending on `gksu`. But this is not true:

```
$ apt-cache rdepends gksu
gksu
Reverse Depends:
  gexec
  wicd-gtk
  spacefm-gtk3
  spacefm
 |menu

$ aptitude why gksu 
i   menu Suggests gksu | kde-runtime | ktsuss
```

As you see some software, which are distibuted by third-party may depend on `gksu` package. So you can proceed installing `gksu` with method below on your own risk.

## How to fix?

Possible solution is to install version from previous (17.10, *artful*) release.

**Warning: do not execute the commands below if unsure!**

### Short method (as @MK suggested)

```
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libg/libgtop2/libgtop-2.0-10_2.32.0-1_amd64.deb
sudo apt install ./libgtop-2.0-10_2.32.0-1_amd64.deb

wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/libg/libgksu/libgksu2-0_2.0.13~pre1-6ubuntu8_amd64.deb
sudo apt install ./libgksu2-0_2.0.13~pre1-6ubuntu8_amd64.deb

wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/gksu/gksu_2.0.2-9ubuntu1_amd64.deb
sudo apt install ./gksu_2.0.2-9ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

## Test

Test `gksu` (should work on Xorg-sessions)

```
gksu-properties # check that it has "Authentication mode" to "sudo"
gksu date
gksudo date
```

## Notes

After installation the following packages will be marked as obsolete (locally-installed): `gksu`, `libgksu2-0`. But they will work as expected.

Comment: just to be sure, won't I have issues in the future having `gksu` installed on 18.04 ? or I have to remove it after I am done with App installation ?

Comment: @N0rbert: Instead of adding the whole shabang, which you admit is dangerous, you can just download the lib .deb from https://packages.ubuntu.com/artful/amd64/libgksu2-0/download and the gksu .deb file from https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/bionic/amd64/gksu/2.0.2-9ubuntu1. Install the lib first using `gdebi`, followed by the gksu, also using `gedbi`

Comment: @MK, thanks, I added your method to the answer.

Comment: Running with mixed repositories is a horrible idea.  If you must, at least set up [Apt Pinning](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PinningHowto).

Answer (score 4):

**Mixed repositories**

Adding the *artful* repositories to a *bionic* system is **an absolutely horrible idea.** I cannot stress enough how much suffering the notion, alone, of running with mixed repositories will bring. There shall be misery and gnashing of teeth to the end of the age and beyond.

Masochists, please at least use protection ([Apt Pinning](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PinningHowto)).

**Better ideas**

- Wait for new releases that do not depend on outdated packages.  *(Patience is a virtue that will prevent embarrassing visits to the Help Center with conf-files, or worse, stuck where they don't belong.)*
- Rebuild packages without unnecessary dependencies.
- Find PPAs with the packages you want.
- [Put a wrapper -script- around `pkexec`.](https://askubuntu.com/a/1026821/567307)
- [Faux play -with faux packages- and `equivs`.](https://askubuntu.com/a/656153/567307)

**Notes**

- `kdesudo` has been dropped as well.
- `lxqt-sudo` is still around, but didn't work for me.
- Something called `gosa`? No idea what it is.
- Might as well play `sudoku` until this mess is figured out.