# Configuration of account realvnc vncconnect

Tags: 18.04, vnc

I've had trouble with configuring realVnc before, but not this particular issue.  I'm on ubuntu 18.04, and have grabbed the installer from https://www.realvnc.com/en/connect/download/vnc/linux/

The instructions at https://www.realvnc.com/en/connect/docs/debian-install-remove.html I'm not sure if they just aren't specific enough or what.

Under licensing VNC server is the information:

> Open the VNC Server dialog and select Licensing from the menu to open the graphical License Wizard. Follow the instructions to sign in with your RealVNC account credentials.

No real indication on ***how*** to do the above, but the closest I've been able to find was running:

`systemctl start vncserver-x11-serviced.service`

This tells me I need to login with my account, all expected stuff.  However, once done authenticating with my account information, and picking a password for connecting to this particular machine, I am presented with:

[image]

I'm extremely new to ubuntu and linux in general, I just mostly want a cloud hosted way to track the machines I can remote into, which is why I was using realVnc (and it came with my pi)

Anyone have any idea what I need to do to provide admin privileges?

Comment: Have you tried `tightvncserver`?  There is no licensing involved with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From other pc, windows, start putty + xming app (x11 enabled) ssh to linux, login user, than start in console: vnclicensewiz, connect realvnc email+passwd than  vnc passwd (2x), ok -> (need root passwd) work!

Comment: Thanks! I didn't actually even need to go through x11 ssh, just running `sudo vnclicensewiz` was enough.  Funny at least in my quick glance through the installation instructions I found no reference to `vnclicensewiz`.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is licensing the software locally from the console...   sorry.

```
sudo vnclicense -add [KEY]<br>
```

Direct connectivity is automatically enabled.
To enable cloud connectivity, use

```
sudo vncserver-x11 -service -joinCloud TOKEN [-joinGroup GROUP-NAME]...
```

This link may also be helpful:
https://www.realvnc.com/en/connect/docs/debian-install-remove.html

Answer (score 1):

real vnc uses gksu to get administrative privileges
Ubuntu 18.04 has not gksu
[[Why is gksu no longer installed by default?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/284306/why-is-gksu-no-longer-installed-by-default])

you can install it following the method explained in this link [[How to install an application that requires gksu package on ubuntu 18.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1030054/how-to-install-an-application-that-requires-gksu-package-on-ubuntu-18-04])

Once done, you will be able to manage the interface

Answer (score 0):

After starting the RealVNC server with the command you used:
systemctl start vncserver-x11-serviced.service

You should see a new icon [V2] appear in the top right hand corner of your screen (to the left of the wifi, volume & battery icons).

Click on the icon and then on the "Licensing" option. A screen titled "VNC Server  Licensing" appears. Select the option "Sign in to your RealVNC account", click Next and then provide the useid and password for your RealVNC account.

If you don't have an account: Go to their website and register one.

You will then be asked to provide a password specific to accessing this server.
Follow the remaining prompts.