# Samba GUI will not start 18.04

Tags: samba

Went to Ubuntu Software installed Samba 1.2.63-0ubuntu6.

Clicked 'Launch'... nothing happens

Does not show up in 'Show Applications'

Answer (score 11):

I had the same exact issue. To fix it I ran:

```
sudo system-config-samba
```

The very last line of the output read:

```
SystemError: could not open configuration file '/etc/libuser.conf': No such file or directory
```

I simply created the file by using:

```
sudo touch /etc/libuser.conf
```

and it worked fine.

I couldn't seem to get it to appear in the application screen, but can be run by

```
sudo system-config-samba
```

from the terminal.

Comment: It won't show up in the application screen because /usr/share/applicaions/system-config-samba.desktop is designed to run "gksu system-config-samba". There is no gksu in Ubuntu 18.04. system-config-samba is no longer maintained and some of it's options will actually disable the samba service ( smbd ) from running. It will eventually cease to exist I suspect: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/system-config-samba/+bug/1740419 Side note: Please add a -H between sudo and system-config-samba. As in "sudo -H system-config-samba"

Comment: Morbius1:  Do you know, are there graphical samba configuration tools similar to and with the simplicity of system-config-samba that will work in Bionic and later?

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer will get it working but there is a way to fix it not showing up on the applications screen.

gksu is one of the dependencies of samba.
gksu was removed from the Ubuntu package library in 18.04
This is the reason samba doesn't show up in the applications screen.

One way to fix this is to install the version of gksu used in Ubuntu 17.10

To do this folow these instructions (from here https://askubuntu.com/a/1030066)

1. Add artful repositories to the system:

   ```
   cat <<EOF | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/artful.list
   deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ artful universe
   EOF
   ```
2. Update package cache

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   ```
3. Install gksu package

   ```
   sudo apt-get install gksu
   ```
4. Remove artful repository from system for safety

   ```
   sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/artful.list
   sudo apt-get update
   ```

After youv'e done this uninstall samba from the command line using:

```
sudo apt autoremove samba
```

Then install samba again from the *Ubuntu software center*.

It is important that you install it from the Ubuntu software center and not from the command line. It wont work if you do it from the command line. I have no idea why, it just doesn't.

Samba should now show up in the applications screen.

Comment: This seems quite hacky to me as you are mixing packages from two versions of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

For those who don't mind typing password in terminal the easiest way to replace the shortcut to samba is to edit the `.desktop` file. In my case on Xubuntu it's located in `/usr/share/applications/` and `~/.local/share/applications/`

Just edit the file `system-config-samba.desktop` or `samba.desktop` with a text editor, and replace the line

```
Exec=gksu system-config-samba
```

with

```
Exec=sudo system-config-samba
```

and the line:

```
Terminal=False
```

to

```
Terminal=true
```

Comment: I would recommend using `sudo -H system-config-samba` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I simply do `sudo system-config-samba` and all is working fine.  The Samba GUI is shown as expected.