# PKEXEC: No display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable

Tags: xubuntu, pkexec

I've installed XAMPP but I haven't got desktop entry so I created one. I'm using pkexec because it requests authorization. The problem is when I run my new desktop file nothing happens after I enter password. Here's the file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Xampp
GenericName=Localhost Server
Exec=pkexec /opt/lampp/manager-linux-x64.run
Terminal=false
Icon=/opt/lampp/XAMPP.png
Type=Application
Categories=Programming;Development;
```

When I execute Exec line in terminal, this is the error I get after entering password:
[image]

What is this about?

Comment: See this: [How to configure pkexec?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/287845/how-to-configure-pkexec)