# Unable to start XAMPP using sudo in Desktop Entry

Tags: 18.04, .desktop, xampp

I am using Ubuntu 18.04. I have installed XAMPP and created a .desktop file to run it.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=XAMPP Control Panel
Version=7.3.0.0
Exec=sudo -i python /opt/lampp/share/xampp-control-panel/xampp-control-panel.py
Encoding=UTF-8
Terminal=false
Comment=Start and Stop XAMPP
Icon=/home/lee/.local/favicon.ico
```

But, for some reason it won't run. The "Exec" line runs fine on the CL. I have it set to execute. Any ideas?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100552/discussion-between-kulfy-and-lee).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution, with thanks to @Kulfy

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
[Desktop Entry]
Name=XAMPP
Type=Application
Exec=sh -c "pkexec env DISPLAY=$DISPLAY XAUTHORITY=$XAUTHORITY sudo /opt/lampp/manager-linux-x64.run"
Terminal=false
Icon=/opt/lampp/htdocs/favicon.ico
Terminal=false
```

Answer (score 6):

To run applications in distributions like Ubuntu where root account is disabled by default, `sudo` is used. When `sudo` with a command is run in Terminal, it asks for the password. But when it is used in Desktop entry, there is no way by default to provide that. However, to run the application as superuser using a Desktop entry, below methods can be adopted.

1. #### Using **`Terminal`** Key:

   The **`Terminal`** key allows the application to execute in Terminal,i.e., the command line used in **`Exec`** would run as if it was executed in terminal opening a new terminal window and allowing user to enter the password. The key should be appended like this:

   ```
   Terminal=true
   ```

   But this method has an issue. Since it opens an extra application, i.e. the terminal window, it results in extra RAM and CPU cycles consumption.
2. #### Using `pkexec`:

   Another way is to use `pkexec`. `pkexec` opens a graphical window to provide password. But it doesn't allow to run X11 applications as another user since the `$DISPLAY` and `$XAUTHORITY` environment variables are not set (Reference: [Radu Rădeanu's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/332847/816190)).

   However the variables won't be expanded in desktop entry since it ain't a shell. Therefore, you can run the command using shell, i.e.

   ```
   Exec=sh -c 'pkexec env DISPLAY=$DISPLAY XAUTHORITY=$XAUTHORITY /path/to/executable'
   ```

   You can use `bash` or any supported shell instead of `bash`.

   But this  would create an sh or bash process which would wait for the application to exit, thus consuming some memory.
3. #### Editing `/etc/sudoers`:

   Some applications such as XAMPP needs to be run as superuser. You can allow some specific applications to run without even asking for password by editing `/etc/sudoers` and adding the application there.

   - To allow all sudoers to run the application without password, append the below line to `/etc/sudoers`.

     ```
     %sudo ALL = (root) NOPASSWD: /path/to/application
     ```
   - To allow specific user in sudoer to run the application without password, append

     ```
     USER ALL = (root) NOPASSWD: /path/to/application
     ```

     for example:

     ```
     kulfy ALL = (root) NOPASSWD: /opt/lampp/manager-linux-x64.run
     ```

   To append through command line, you can use [`tee`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/cosmic/man1/tee.1.html) with option `a`. Example:

   ```
   echo 'kulfy ALL = (root) NOPASSWD: /opt/lampp/manager-linux-x64.run' | sudo tee -a /etc/sudoers
   ```

   **Warning:** Don't overwrite the content of `/etc/sudoers`, otherwise you won't be able to perform sudo actions. Only **append** the above line. It is recommended to have a backup of that file.

---

**Footnote:** To use XAMPP Control Panel manager-linux-x64.run should be executed instead of xampp-control-panel.py. The earlier is an executable binary file and responsible for showing the GUI while the Python script is a part it, i.e. it is not the complete Control Panel.

Comment: According to the information [here](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/visudo.htm), there is a special way to edit the /etc/sudoers file. I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: @Lee That's one of the method to edit files with sudo privileges. It's basically Vi/Vim with sudo. If you are familiar with Vi, you can use that. Personally I use `sudoedit` which uses `EDITOR` which is set to nano by default. Or simply `sudo nano`.