# How to create a .desktop entry for .run file

Tags: .desktop

I tried to add a new Desktop Entry but it failed...
I think the reason is the run file type.

Is it possible to make a .desktop entry for a run file?

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.1
Type=Application
Name=XAMPP
Comment=XAMPP Control Panel
Icon=/opt/lampp/htdocs/dashboard/images/xampp-logo.svg
Exec=/opt/lampp/manager-linux-x64.run
Path=/opt/lampp
Actions=
Categories=Development;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to start XAMPP using sudo in Desktop Entry](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1107574/unable-to-start-xampp-using-sudo-in-desktop-entry). You need to provide sudo privileges to XAMPP to start.