# Add a shell script with sudo to launcher as shortcut in Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: 19.10, desktop-icons

I tried adding a desktop shortcut like described here

- [How can I create launchers on my desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64222/how-can-i-create-launchers-on-my-desktop)
- [How can I edit/create new launcher items in Unity by hand?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13758/how-can-i-edit-create-new-launcher-items-in-unity-by-hand)

but those answers seem to be outdated since 19.10

I try to add this script as launcher on my desktop:

```
sudo /usr/local/sbin/turbo-boost.sh toggle
```

you find the script and my try to add it as desktop icon here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/547261/20661

---

UPDATE:

The `.desktop` file doesn't work if I click on it in the default file browser `nautilus` in Ubuntu 19.10, but it works fine in a `thunar` window.

I tried this now: I created another launcher with the command line

```
Exec=sudo /usr/bin/tempfile
```

which behaves strange:

- If I call this in `nautilus` it creates a temp file which belongs to my user
- If called in `thunar`, it asks for sudo password in another shell window and then creates a temp file that belongs to root

Comment: Is that shortcut opening in text editor? Or isn't  shortcut doing anything?

Comment: I get the error `gdbus.error: ...unknown xorg.xfce.panel was not provided by any .service files` and nothing happens

Comment: i need to know,  is the script runs as expected when you executing it in terminal?

Comment: Sure, If I add sudo and I added my user correctly to the sudoers file

Comment: But I don't need to enter the password, I am allowed in sudoers

Comment: I have posted [an answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1185418/816190) to a similar question. There I talked about 3 ways to create a desktop entry for an application that requires sudo privileges. That might be helpful just in case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This .desktop-file works if you have an entry in sudoers:

```
my_username_here ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/local/sbin/turbo-boost.sh
```

Make sure, you add an entry `Path` and `GenericName` and put it in this location: `/usr/share/applications/toggle-turbo-boost.desktop`

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=true
Name=toggle turbo-boost
Icon=/usr/share/icons/Humanity/apps/64/gkdebconf-icon.svg
Exec=sudo /usr/local/sbin/turbo-boost.sh toggle
X-MultipleArgs=false
Categories=GNOME;GTK;
StartupNotify=true
GenericName=Toggle Turbo-Boost
Path=/tmp/
```

It is not possible to click on it in nautilus, but you can search for i in the dash:

1. press SUPER and search for "Toggle Turbo Boost", you will see the icon.
2. press ENTER to execute, or right click to "Add to Favorites" which will add a button in the quick-start bar.