# Permissions denied in QGIS (perhaps all KDE programs)?

Tags: unity, kde, 14.04

Encountering a crash when requesting QGIS 2.2 to access data on desktop machine. Running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Running QGIS desktop as root via the terminal does allow me to open files! But it also pops up with an error message immediately after the program runs (ie after the initial loading/welcome graphic dissapears):

The layer /usr/share/applications/%F is not a valid layer and can not be added to the map

Any idea how I can make QGIS operate from GUI (unity) with root privileges without having to open it via terminal and adding the sudo prefix?

I have attempted the solution provided below by edm, but the open window hangs and I recieve errors pertaining to klauncher: Could not start process Cannot talk to klauncher: Not connected to D-Bus server. [How to launch application as root from Unity Launcher?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/118822/how-to-launch-application-as-root-from-unity-launcher)

It might be that my KDE profile has been corrupted. Any ideas how I can rectify this so that I can run qgis from unity?

I'm still a beginner at this, so please provide any instructions should I require to post more command outputs.

```
$ qgis
Warning: loading of qt translation failed [/usr/share/qt4/translations/qt_en_AU]
```

qgis.bin(32381)/KSharedDataCache KSharedDataCache::Private::mapSharedMemory: Failed to establish shared memory mapping, will fallback to private memory -- memory usage will increase 
    kbuildsycoca4 running...
    kbuildsycoca4: ERROR creating database '/home/lyndon/.kde/cache-Gerhard-ThinkPad-W530/ksycoca4'! Insufficient permissions in target directory.
    Warning: ERROR: Running KSycoca failed.
    QGIS died on signal 11ptrace: Operation not permitted.
    No thread selected
    No stack.
    gdb returned 0
    Aborted (core dumped)'

Any request, such as opening a file, browsing, creating a new project etc. will cause this crash.

Output of:

```
sudo ls -l /home/lyndon/.kde/cache-Gerhard-ThinkPad-W530/ 

total 10320 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 10547304 Apr 25 2013 icon-cache.kcache –
```

Running the program by root (via terminal) works. But a new error occurs:

```
$ sudo qgis %F


Warning: loading of qt translation failed [/usr/share/qt4/translations/qt_en_AU]
Error: "/tmp/kde-lyndon" is owned by uid 1000 instead of uid 0.
Error: "/tmp/ksocket-lyndon" is owned by uid 1000 instead of uid 0.
Error: "/tmp/kde-lyndon" is owned by uid 1000 instead of uid 0.
```

kdeinit4: Shutting down running client.
    Connecting to deprecated signal QDBusConnectionInterface::serviceOwnerChanged(QString,QString,QString)
    Error: "/tmp/ksocket-lyndon" is owned by uid 1000 instead of uid 0.
    Error: "/tmp/kde-lyndon" is owned by uid 1000 instead of uid 0.
    QDBusConnection: session D-Bus connection created before QCoreApplication. Application may misbehave.
    QDBusConnection: session D-Bus connection created before QCoreApplication. Application may misbehave.
    kbuildsycoca4 running...
    kbuildsycoca4(8139) VFolderMenu::loadDoc: Parse error in  "/home/lyndon/.config/menus/applications-merged/xdg-desktop-menu-dummy.menu" , line  1 , col  1 :  "unexpected end of file" 
kbuildsycoca4(8139)/kdecore (services) KServicePrivate::init: The desktop entry file  "/usr/share/applications/evolution-data-server-uoa.desktop"  has Type= "Application"  but no Exec line

```
kbuildsycoca4(8139) KBuildServiceFactory::createEntry: Invalid Service :  "/usr/share/applications/evolution-data-server-uoa.desktop"
```

kbuildsycoca4(8139)/kdecore (services) KServicePrivate::parseActions: The desktop file "/usr/share/applications/Launchpadlaunchpadnet.desktop" references the action "S0" but doesn't define it 
    kbuildsycoca4(8139)/kdecore (services) KServicePrivate::parseActions: The desktop file "/usr/share/applications/Launchpadlaunchpadnet.desktop" references the action "S1" but doesn't define it 
    kbuildsycoca4(8139)/kdecore (services) KServicePrivate::parseActions: The desktop file "/usr/share/applications/Launchpadlaunchpadnet.desktop" references the action "S2" but doesn't define it 
    kbuildsycoca4(8139)/kdecore (services) KServicePrivate::parseActions: The desktop file "/usr/share/applications/Launchpadlaunchpadnet.desktop" references the action "S3" but doesn't define it 
    kbuildsycoca4(8139)/kdecore (services) KServicePrivate::parseActions: The desktop file "/usr/share/applications/Launchpadlaunchpadnet.desktop" references the action "S4" but doesn't define it 
    kbuildsycoca4(8139)/kdecore (services) KServicePrivate::parseActions: The desktop file "/usr/share/applications/Launchpadlaunchpadnet.desktop" references the action "S5" but doesn't define it 
    kbuildsycoca4(8139)/kdecore (services) KServicePrivate::parseActions: The desktop file "/usr/share/applications/Launchpadlaunchpadnet.desktop" references the action "S6" but doesn't define it 
     kbuildsycoca4(8139)/kdecore (services) KServicePrivate::parseActions: The desktop file "/usr/share/applications/Launchpadlaunchpadnet.desktop" references the action "S7" but doesn't define it 
    kbuildsycoca4(8139)/kdecore (services) KServicePrivate::parseActions: The desktop file "/usr/share/applications/Launchpadlaunchpadnet.desktop" references the action "S8" but doesn't define it 
    kbuildsycoca4(8139)/kdecore (services) KServicePrivate::parseActions: The desktop file "/usr/share/applications/Launchpadlaunchpadnet.desktop" references the action "S9" but doesn't define it 
    kbuildsycoca4(8139)/kdecore (services) KServicePrivate::parseActions: The desktop file "/usr/share/applications/Launchpadlaunchpadnet.desktop" references the action "S10" but doesn't define it 
    kbuildsycoca4(8139)/kdecore (services) KServicePrivate::init: The desktop entry file  "/usr/share/applications/unity-scope-gdrive.desktop"  has Type= "Application"  but no Exec line

```
kbuildsycoca4(8139) KBuildServiceFactory::createEntry: Invalid Service :  "/usr/share/applications/unity-scope-gdrive.desktop" 
KBuildServiceFactory::createEntry: Invalid Service :  "/usr/share/applications/updf.desktop"
kbuildsycoca4(8139)/kdecore (services) KServicePrivate::init: The desktop entry file "/usr/share/applications/updf.desktop" has Type= " Application" instead of "Application" or "Service" 
kbuildsycoca4(8139) KBuildServiceFactory::createEntry: Invalid Service :  "/usr/share/applications/updf.desktop"
kbuildsycoca4(8139) KBuildServiceFactory::createEntry: Invalid Service :  "/usr/share/applications/unity-lens-photos.desktop" 
kbuildsycoca4(8139) kdemain: Emitting notifyDatabaseChanged ("servicetypes", "xdgdata-mime", "services", "apps")
Error: "/tmp/kde-lyndon" is owned by uid 1000 instead of uid 0.
Warning: Object::connect: No such signal org::freedesktop::UPower::DeviceAdded(QDBusObjectPath)
Warning: Object::connect: No such signal org::freedesktop::UPower::DeviceRemoved(QDBusObjectPath)
Error: "/tmp/ksocket-lyndon" is owned by uid 1000 instead of uid 0.
Object::connect: No such signal org::freedesktop::UPower::DeviceAdded(QDBusObjectPath)
Object::connect: No such signal org::freedesktop::UPower::DeviceRemoved(QDBusObjectPath)
```

Comment: This problem was solved by entering the following command:

`sudo chown -R lyndon:lyndon /home/lyndon/.kde/cache-lyndon-ThinkPad-W530/`

Answer (score 1):

This problem was solved by entering the following command:

```
sudo chown -R lyndon:lyndon /home/lyndon/.kde/cache-lyndon-ThinkPad-W530/
```