# File Permissions and umask

Tags: command-line, permissions, php, sublime-text

I am new to linux in general and have figured out the different programs belong to different groups. I can easily solve my own problem by typing sudo all the time. But I'd rather understand the why of the problem and fix it permanently.

I've installed php as part of the lamp-stack. Everything work fines. However when I open a file with PHPStorm or Sublime Text I have problems working with files. I can get around this already by typing..
sudo chown -R myusername /path/to/file

I've read that I can use umask to explore this further. But that's as far as I can figure out so far.

How can I permamently set permissions in the programs (phpstorm, sublime text) so that they can work with the files in /var/www/html so that they can be worked with without using sudo to open them, or keep having to change ownership of them all the time?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use chmod command to change the permission, [How to use Chmod command](http://www.unixtutorial.org/2014/07/difference-between-chmod-and-chown/), or You can lunch the app as Root, [How to launch application as root](https://askubuntu.com/questions/118822/how-to-launch-application-as-root-from-unity-launcher)

Comment: Thank you terdon, pilot, heemayl and Byte Commander for pointing me in the correct thread. I did not know how to ask the right question. For Aby, the question I asked was specfically how to NOT launch the application as root. But thanks for trying. :)

Comment: NP, For this reason I also add the Chmod command explanation, I actually prefer to launch them like root and not change or add permissions  to anyone.