# pkexec command in a .desktop file

Tags: command-line, .desktop, pkexec

I made a .desktop file for Androxyde's Flashtool (utility for Sony Xperia devices that I have to open with an executable file in its folder) that requires root privileges to use fastboot utilities.
I used to make it work with `gksu`, but I'm on Ubuntu 15.04 and gksu is now old.

I tried to modify the `exec` line from

```
Exec=gksu /home/natasha/FlashTool/FlashTool
```

to

```
Exec=pkexec /home/natasha/FlashTool/FlashTool
```

Then, I read about pkexec doesn't allow to run X11 applications and so I override in this way:

[image]

[Link to full image on Imgur.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hNrWx.png)

The problem now is: It asks me the password but the Flashtool's GUI doesn't start.
BUT if I execute that command in terminal, the program starts without problems. What can I do?

[image]

[Link to full image on Imgur.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q6cEh.png)

Comment: pkexec needs a policy file to work, you would need to create one, some info here - http://www.freedesktop.org/software/polkit/docs/0.105/pkexec.1.html or use existing ones to see how done, - /usr/share/polkit-1/actions. Do note that policies are sometimes better off when part of an app install, (ie. work without issue), if you get a 'Cannot open display' error then there are workarounds such as http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2225832&p=13031607&viewfull=1#post13031607

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Create a new file in `/usr/share/polkit-1/actions/`

```
sudo nano /usr/share/polkit-1/actions/FlashTool.policy
```

and add the lines below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE policyconfig PUBLIC
 "-//freedesktop//DTD PolicyKit Policy Configuration 1.0//EN"
 "http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/PolicyKit/1/policyconfig.dtd">

<policyconfig>

  <action id="org.freedesktop.policykit.pkexec.run-FlashTool">
    <description>Run FlashTool</description>
    <message>Authentication is required to run FlashTool</message>
    <defaults>
      <allow_any>no</allow_any>
      <allow_inactive>no</allow_inactive>
      <allow_active>auth_admin_keep</allow_active>
    </defaults>
    <annotate key="org.freedesktop.policykit.exec.path">/home/natasha/FlashTool/FlashTool</annotate>
    <annotate key="org.freedesktop.policykit.exec.allow_gui">TRUE</annotate>
  </action>

</policyconfig>
```

---

Then create a new file `/home/natasha/FlashTool/`

```
nano /home/natasha/FlashTool/flashtool-pkexec
```

and add the lines below:

```
#!/bin/sh
pkexec "/home/natasha/FlashTool/FlashTool" "$@"
```

---

Use the line below for `Exec` in your `desktop` file:

```
Exec=/home/natasha/FlashTool/flashtool-pkexec
```

---

**Tested** on my system Ubuntu 15.04 GNOME with the following files:

---

```
$ cat /usr/share/applications/gedit.root.desktop 
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Gedit as root
GenericName=Text Editor
X-GNOME-FullName=
Comment=
Exec=gedit-pkexec
Icon=gedit
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=GNOME;System;Filesystem;Settings;
StartupNotify=true
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=gedit

$ cat /usr/share/polkit-1/actions/gedit.policy 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE policyconfig PUBLIC
 "-//freedesktop//DTD PolicyKit Policy Configuration 1.0//EN"
 "http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/PolicyKit/1/policyconfig.dtd">

<policyconfig>

  <action id="org.freedesktop.policykit.pkexec.run-FlashTool">
    <description>Run FlashTool</description>
    <message>Authentication is required to run FlashTool</message>
    <defaults>
      <allow_any>no</allow_any>
      <allow_inactive>no</allow_inactive>
      <allow_active>auth_admin_keep</allow_active>
    </defaults>
    <annotate key="org.freedesktop.policykit.exec.path">/usr/bin/gedit</annotate>
    <annotate key="org.freedesktop.policykit.exec.allow_gui">TRUE</annotate>
  </action>

</policyconfig>

$ cat /usr/bin/gedit-pkexec 
#!/bin/sh
pkexec "gedit" "$@"
```

Comment: It works! The only thing I modified is on the `Exec` command: I wrote
 `Exec=pkexec /home/natasha/FlashTool/FlashTool`
like before, because flashtool-pkexec doesn't work on the .desktop file. Thanks to the policy file it works like a charm. Thank you!

Comment: @nplezka To run a shell script from a .desktop file, even with `#!`, you need to prefix the `Exec` command with `/bin/sh`.

Comment: Had to run `chmod +x` to allow my script executing first, but it worked!

Answer (score 2):

You may also change

```
Exec=APP_COMMAND
```

to

```
Exec=sh -c "pkexec env DISPLAY=$DISPLAY XAUTHORITY=$XAUTHORITY APP_COMMAND"
```

That way you will get asked about the password and the program starts as usual.

(See [How to launch application as root from Unity Launcher?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/118822/how-to-launch-application-as-root-from-unity-launcher) for more information and reasoning. TL;DR: `sh -c` starts it in a shell, where the follow-up code worked, as the op confirmed. `pkexec` then starts the "APP_COMMAND" as root but needs the environment variables to actually be able to start a GUI application.)

Answer (score 0):

`sudo -H` is enough to start a graphical application preventing changes to the user's configuration files in `~/`, since it sets the running environment's home directory to root's home directory:

```
Exec=sudo -H /home/natasha/FlashTool/FlashTool
```

Comment: In a `desktop` file?

Comment: @A.B. Yes, why not?

Comment: @A.B. It's the same as running it in a whatever `sh` instance (probably with some environment variables set ad hoc, but here's not a problem).

Comment: I don't think it's going to ask for your password and launch the application with `sudo` if you have `Terminal=false` line in the `.desktop` launcher (as OP has here). However most probably it would work with `Terminal=true` instead.

Answer (score 0):

The content of the desktop file (`/usr/share/applications/Flashtool.desktop` or `~/.local/share/applications/Flashtool.desktop`).

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Flashtool
GenericName=Flashtool
Comment=Tool for Xperia Devices
Type=Application
Categories=Qt;FileTransfer;Chat
Terminal=false
Icon=/usr/share/icons/Numix-Circle-Light/48x48/apps/nitrotasks.svg
Exec=/home/natasha/FlashTool/FlashTool
Actions=new-root-window

[Desktop Action new-root-window]
Name=New Root Window
Exec=sh -c "pkexec --disable-internal-agent env DISPLAY=$DISPLAY XAUTHORITY=$XAUTHORITY /home/natasha/FlashTool/FlashTool"
Terminal=true
```

Right-click on the Desktop icon and select `New Root Window`.