# How to run Desktop Entry command as a root (Exec=path)

Tags: 18.04, .desktop

I'm tired to add XAMPP Desktop shortcut/Luncher in my ubuntu 18.04LTS.
Exec path. sudo command not executed such as `admin:// command` got error to run the command. How do I create XAMPP desktop shortcut on Ubuntu 18.04LTS ?

[image: ScreenShot]

Comment: Try using `pkexec`.

Comment: It might work with `sudo -H`, but `pkexec` provides higher security.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.

I find out that the package gksu (gksudo) [has been deprecated](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=892768). first [removed from Debian](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/gksu) and then [Canonical decided to drop it from Ubuntu 18.04](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/umit/+bug/1740618). Application developers are suggested to use PolicyKit (pkexec) instead.

I suggest to look at [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/641593/pkexec-command-in-a-desktop-file) thread about using pkexec command in a .desktop file. I haven't try it yet (it looks a bit like an overkill for me and I don't want to mess sth up).

That's what I've got. Maybe someone else will have a better and simpler solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have following workaround. Set `Terminal=true` and `Exec=sudo bash...`

Like here:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=myApplication
Comment=myApplication
Exec=sudo bash .../myApplication
Icon=YOUR_ICON
Terminal=true
```

A terminal will open and you can type your password. Maybe there is an easier solution