# How to add a program shortcut which runs via sudo to 'Show Applications > All Applications' & Dock in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, lamp, .desktop, xampp, ubuntu-dock

I have [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html) installed, it is a PHP/MySQL environment and has a control panel which can be launched using this command:

```
sudo /opt/lampp/manager-linux-x64.run
```

That works.

I want to create a launcher shortcut so it appears in 'Show Applications > All Applications' and in the dock.

In Ubuntu 16.04 Unity I did this using a launcher file in the share/applications folder and worked fine.

I only seem to find instruction on adding this as a 'desktop shortcut' with 18.04, see: https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-create-desktop-shortcut-launcher-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux

I have attempted a desktop launcher with this code:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Exec=sudo /opt/lampp/manager-linux-x64.run
Name=Test
Comment=Test
```

This creates a file on the desktop, I have set to run as an application in the file properties, upon running it asks if this should be trusted to which I confirm (on a side note - is there a list of these somewhere?) but it does not run.

All the other questions related to this are attempting to use `gksudo` (which is deprecated in 18.04), `sudo -H nautilus` or `pkexec`, which doesn't even run via terminal, this returns:

```
pkexec env DISPLAY=1 XAUTHORITY=$XAUTHROTIY /opt/lampp/manager-linux-x64.run
Unknown Error couldn't connect to display "1"
```

Comment: See this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/641593/pkexec-command-in-a-desktop-file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pkexec command in a .desktop file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/641593/pkexec-command-in-a-desktop-file)

Answer (score 0):

Advise is to use the [gvfs admin back end](https://github.com/brunonova/nautilus-admin/issues/29), this is available from Ubuntu 17.10 onwards.
Change your exec line to be:

```
Exec=admin://opt/lampp/manager-linux-x64.run
```