# Gksudo alternatives, especially to use in .desktop files

Tags: sudo, .desktop, gksudo

I have wanted to create a `.desktop` file to create an application icon which would execute a `.run` file as admin. Since the `gksu` package is deprecated, I've used

```
Exec=gnome-terminal --command="sudo /opt/lampp/manager-linux-x64.run"
```

in the `.desktop` file. This opens a new terminal window and I type my sudo password to open the application.

So, are there any better solutions, which are more elegant for instance without having a terminal window opened?

Comment: Also see this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/641593/pkexec-command-in-a-desktop-file