# VS Code doesn't open from command line as root

Tags: command-line, 18.04, visual-studio-code

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS (Bionic Beaver). I'm trying to run VS Code using these commands:

```
>> sudo -s
# mkdir ../user-data-dir
# cd <project_path>
<project_path># code . --userdata-dir ../user-data-dir
<project_path>#
```

I used to launch VS Code using these commands as root before, but now it is not working. I get no errors in the command line.

`code .` does open VS Code if I'm not running as root.

Help please?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run Visual Studio Code as root](https://askubuntu.com/questions/803343/how-to-run-visual-studio-code-as-root)

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra `.` in your command. Try this:

```
code  --userdata-dir /your/path
```

Comment: still doesn't launch the vscode