# How to change configuration of Unity shortcut permanently?

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys

I need to launch an application from the unity shortcut as root user. So, I've edit unity shortcut configuration file according to this advice [How to launch application as root from Unity Launcher?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/118822/how-to-launch-application-as-root-from-unity-launcher). It's working correctly. But after computer reboot, the content of `~/.local/share/applications/APPNAME.desktop` is reset to default state. Now, I have to edit the config file everytime I start Ubuntu. Is here the way how to make it permanently? Thank you.

Comment: What is the application? If it overwrrites the custom launcher, it must be one you can set/unset autostart from its prefs.

Comment: JetBrains PyCharm

Comment: On first run, it offers to make a desktop entry. Did you choose (tick) "for all users", just for current user or Cancel?

Comment: I'm sorry, I have no idea. But thank you very much, because your first comment helps me out from this. I've created custom .desktop file and lock it to launcher. It's working now. If you would like, just formulate the comment as an answer and I'll mark it. Thank you