# Execute a desktop shortcut to a jar file on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: java, 18.04, launcher, root, .desktop

I need to run a .desktop file as an admin but I have issues achieving this. I am working with this `.desktop` file

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Some Application
Exec="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java" -Xmx768M -jar /opt/some/application/boot.jar
Icon=/opt/some/application/logo.png
Categories=Application;
```

I am running Ubuntu 18.04. I have found [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/118822/how-to-launch-application-as-root-from-unity-launcher) question here but it does not work for Ubuntu 18.04.

I tried putting an `admin://` in front of it as well but that did not work either:

Neither

```
Exec="admin:///usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java" -Xmx768M -jar /opt/some/application/boot.jar
```

nor

```
Exec=admin:///usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java -Xmx768M -jar /opt/some/application/boot.jar
```

work. If I want to execute that file from the command line it only opens the content. Any help is highly appreciated. I was unable to find anything on Google in regard to Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: What command from that question did you try?

Comment: I have tried all of them

Answer (score 0):

Defining Path might help. The following works for me:

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Exec=java -jar '/home/cenap/someprogram.jar'
Path=/home/cenap/
Name=SomeProgram
Comment=SomeProgram
Icon=/home/cenap/SomeProgram-icon.png
```