# How to create a desktop shortcut that launches a command line program as root without requiring password

Tags: sudo, .desktop

I'm trying to create a desktop shortcut that changes my monitor input by executing `sudo /usr/bin/ddcutil -d 1 setvcp 60 0xF` without requiring a password. I've made an entry in the *sudoers.d* directory and if the command is run from the terminal no password is required as expected, but when I click on the shortcut it prompts for a password. How what needs to be done to make this shortcut run without a password?

.desktop file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Type=Application
Name=Windows 10
Comment=Switch Display to Windows Virtual Machine
Icon=/usr/share/icons/windows-icon.png
Terminal=true
Exec=sudo /usr/bin/ddcutil -d 1 setvcp 60 0xF
```

sudoers file:

```
myusername ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/ddcutil
```

The solution [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/118822/how-to-launch-application-as-root-from-unity-launcher) doesn't work because gksu is deprecated and using *pkexec* instead as suggested in one of the answers still prompts for a password.

Comment: try "Terminal=false"

Comment: With Terminal=false nothing happens when the shortcut is clicked (i.e. does not ask for password or change the monitor input).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution seems to be using *pkexec* with a *PolicyKit* configuration. [This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/332847/789059) covers more details on the PolicyKit settings. It is geared towards executing GUI applications without requiring a password but mostly applies to non-graphical applications as well.

For my case, the .desktop file was updated to replace *sudo* with *pkexec*. *Terminal=* can be set to either *true* or *false*:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Type=Application
Name=Windows 10
Comment=Switch Display to Windows Virtual Machine
Icon=/usr/share/icons/windows-icon.png
Terminal=false
Exec=pkexec /usr/bin/ddcutil -d 1 setvcp 60 0xF
```

Then, a PolicyKit entry had to be made at */usr/share/polkit-1/actions/com.ubuntu.pkexec.ddcutil.policy*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE policyconfig PUBLIC
  "-//freedesktop//DTD PolicyKit Policy Configuration 1.0//EN"
  "http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/PolicyKit/1/policyconfig.dtd">
<policyconfig>

  <action id="com.ubuntu.pkexec.ddcutil">
    <defaults>
      <allow_active>yes</allow_active>
    </defaults>
    <annotate key="org.freedesktop.policykit.exec.path">/usr/bin/ddcutil</annotate>
  </action>

</policyconfig>
```

*/var/log/auth.log* seems to be where PolicyKit messages are logged if needed for debugging.