# How to configure sudo?

Tags: configuration, sudo, customization

This will probably be a short and informative question.

All the time I have heard and seen people talking about how you can customize sudo so you can adjust the 15 min reset, and add a custom query for the password. I myself would like to know how, and do this(At least on debian based systems). I have DuckDuckGo'd it and I couldn't find anything except the "Sudoers File" in /etc/sudoers, which I haven't found a way to adjust or configure anything from there.

Can anyone tell me the file or where I can configure these settings?

Comment: Take a look at this: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1132821

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://askubuntu.com/questions/118204/sudoers-simple-explanation-requested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check `man sudoers` it states that the timeout can be changed by changing the `timestamp_timeout` variable.

In /etc/sudoers, add this line:

```
Defaults rootpw
```

in order that the default password is the root password and not the user password.

Comment: Well @mutzmatron I have looked into the manual pages.(That is usually the first thing I do...) but I would also like to know where I can customize the prompt for Sys Admin password, and make it ask for root password instead of user...

Comment: That aspect of your question is answered here: http://superuser.com/questions/161593/how-do-i-make-sudo-ask-for-the-root-password, I'll add in the main part...