# Execute custom bash script with sudo without passwd prompt

Tags: bash, sudo, root, scripts

I run ubuntu-12.04 desktop x86_64.
I have a simple script that needs to be accessible from the Desktop and run as root:

```
$ cat ~/Desktop/flash.sh
#!/bin/bash -

cd ~/tools
sudo ~/tools/fastboot-HW.sh
```

I've read [how to run sudo command with no password](https://askubuntu.com/questions/192050/how-to-run-sudo-command-with-no-password) and [sudoers simple explanation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/118204/sudoers-simple-explanation-requested) and [safely execute custom script-parts as sudo](https://serverfault.com/questions/383982/safely-execute-custom-script-parts-as-sudo) (on serverfault) also. I modified my `/etc/sudoers` as follows:

```
$ sudo cat sudoers
Defaults    env_reset
Defaults    secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
root    ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:/home/john/Desktop/flash.sh
john    ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:/home/john/Desktop/flash.sh
root    ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:/home/john/tools/fastboot-HW.sh
john    ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:/home/john/tools/fastboot-HW-sh
```

My sudo-capable user is `john`. He is member of group:

```
john adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare
```

My scripts are fully executable:

```
$ ls -al ~/Desktop/
-rwxr-xr-x  1 john john  129 Feb 13 17:16 flash.sh
$ ls -al ~/tools/
-rwxrwxr-x  1 john john   17251 Feb 13 17:15 fastboot-HW.sh
```

When double-clicking on flash.sh icon on my desktop, and selecting "run in terminal", system still prompts for a passwd. John's passwd is not empty, I'd like to keep it not empty. I also tried to push my 2 scripts to `/usr/local/bin` and adapt `/etc/sudoers` accordingly, but no luck. What I missed must be really obvious, but I cannot find it.

Comment: Take a look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/q/155791/62483) and comment if it worked for you.

Comment: @Lucio the python example script works for me on ubuntu-11.10. Need to check my real script on the ubuntu-12.04 machine.