# sudo su automatically

Tags: 12.04, sudo

It is possible to log in automatically as root after typing `sudo su` - without entering password again?
I know it is not safe, but I want this behavior just for specific IP addresses

Thank you,
Alex

Comment: Yes, but as I said earlier, I want this behavior for specific IPs.
P.S. Not duplicate :)

Comment: opps sorry ...deleted

Comment: possible duplicate of [sudoers - simple explanation requested](http://askubuntu.com/questions/118204/sudoers-simple-explanation-requested)

Comment: this other duplicate has in one of the answers the host syntax

Comment: been there, done that. no success.

Comment: Then you should read it again and check hostname resolution or using ip addresses.  Hosts in sudoers works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a host alias in the sudoers file to specify specic IPs, or subnet ranges ie:

```
Host_Alias  MAIL = 10.0.0.0/255.255.255.0
Host_Alias  FTP = 10.1.0.1, 10.2.0.1

alice   MAIL = (ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
bob          FTP = (ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```