# Change the user in bin/bash

Tags: bash

I want a script X.sh to switch users and perform an action, but so far I have this:

```
 #!/bin/sh

 sudo su partner -s /bin/bash 
 supervisord -c ~/supervisord.conf
exit
```

I want that the user partner execute supervisord and exit, but all I get is a switched user in the comand line a bash shell, doing the `su partner -s /bin/bash` is the only way in which I can access the partner user.

Please Help

Comment: `sudo su partner -c supervisord`?

Comment: Sorry I forgot my .conf file, I tried that way and it did not work, I'll edit my question

Comment: @Rmano Had the right idea. `sudo su partner -s /bin/bash -c 'supervisord -c ~/supervisord.conf'` That is assuming `~/supervisord.conf` is in fact in the partner user's home directory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `sudo -u partner supervisord -C ~/supervisord.conf` instead, and set up your current user in the /etc/sudoers file.  An entry to allow user "current" to execute this command as "partner" would look something like this:

```
current ALL=(partner:partner) NOPASSWD: /path/to/supervisord
```

Make sure and use `visudo` instead of trying to edit the sudoers file manually.  There is a more in-depth but simple explanation of the sudoers file syntax [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/118204/sudoers-simple-explanation-requested).